# How do you insert HTML strings into div containers, and display those containers in a "flex-wrap" row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

These are my HTML Strings, my Javascript array containing the data I'm trying to display, and a for loop that iterates through the array and replaces the %data% in my HTML strings. What I'm trying to do is group Title, Description, and Image for each book together into a container, and then display each book/container in a flex-wrap row on my webpage. I also need to align all the images so that they're flush on the row. Let me know if you know how to do this. Thanks

```js
var HTMLbookStart = '<div class="book-entry"></div>';
var HTMLbookTitle = '<div>%data%</div>';
var HTMLbookDescription = '<div><span class="date-text">%data%</span></div>';
var HTMLbookImages = '<div><br><img src="%data%"></div>';

var books = {
  "recentBooks": [{
      "title": "The Four Steps to the Epiphany",
      "description": "Successful Strategies for Products that Win",
      "images": ["images/Four_Steps.png"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Inspired",
      "description": "How to Create Products Customers Love",
      "images": ["images/Inspired.png"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Never Split the Difference",
      "description": "Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It",
      "images": ["images/Never_Split.png"]
    }
  ],
  "display": function() {

    var book = books.recentBooks.length;
    for (var r = 0; r < book; r++) {
      $("#mybooks").append(HTMLbookStart);
      var formattedBookTitle = HTMLbookTitle.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].title);
      var formattedBookDescription = HTMLbookDescription.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].description);
      var formattedBookImages = HTMLbookImages.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].images);
      $(".book-entry:last").append(formattedBookTitle + formattedBookDescription + formattedBookImages);
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT**

[The final output should look something like this. I'm able to get all the books in a flex-wrap row, but none of the images are aligned. Does anyone know how to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlSk.png)

This is what CSS I'm currently using to achieve this effect. Let me know if you can make it more professional looking.

```css
#mybooks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book-entry {
  text-align:center;
  width: 10%
}
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your current code? Please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @nnnnnn there's nothing wrong with the code itself. I'm trying to make my rows look more professional and flush with each other. Please take a look at my edit to see what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the CSS you mentioned will do it.

To align the images properly, I added a `flex-grow` to the div in the middle

```
#books {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book-entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align:center;
  width: 33%;
}

.book-entry div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow:1
}
```

With your code

```js
var HTMLbookStart = '<div class="book-entry"></div>';
var HTMLbookTitle = '<div>%data%</div>';
var HTMLbookDescription = '<div><span class="date-text">%data%</span></div>';
var HTMLbookImages = '<div><br><img src="%data%"></div>';

var books = {
  "recentBooks": [{
      "title": "The Four Steps",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fringilla sapien in sollicitudin pharetra.",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Inspired",
      "description": "How to Create Products Customers Love",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Never Split the Difference",
      "description": "Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Never Split the Difference",
      "description": "Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Never Split the Difference",
      "description": "Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    },
    {
      "title": "Never Split the Difference",
      "description": "Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It",
      "images": ["https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"]
    }
  ],
  "display": function() {

    var book = books.recentBooks.length;
    for (var r = 0; r < book; r++) {
      $("#books").append(HTMLbookStart);
      var formattedBookTitle = HTMLbookTitle.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].title);
      var formattedBookDescription = HTMLbookDescription.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].description);
      var formattedBookImages = HTMLbookImages.replace("%data%", books.recentBooks[r].images);
      $(".book-entry:last").append(formattedBookTitle + formattedBookDescription + formattedBookImages);
    }
  }
};

books.display()
```

```css
#books {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book-entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align:center;
  width: 33%;
}

.book-entry div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow:1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="books"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks arcs. That worked like a charm, but because the titles/descriptions are different lengths, the images are staggered and not flush throughout the row. Do you have a solution to that as well?

Comment: @AaronLee I made an update, did you mean it like this?

Comment: Hey @arcs, I tried that and no luck. I added an edit to the original to show you what we're dealing with here. Thanks

Comment: @AaronLee are you sure you copied the complete CSS? Because using `display: flex;flex-direction: column;` on book-entry and adding `.book-entry div:nth-child(2) {flex-grow:1}` works for me